# Javascript: Jasmine Error: Expected { 0 : HTMLNode, length : 1 } to be '#containers'

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have spent long time trying to solve this problem. Anyone could help me out with this.

I am following exactly under this youtube tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Huh44nsZTw

when I finish typing this:

```
describe("Experimentation", function() {
var elem;

beforeEach(function() {
    elem = $('<div id="container"><p>Hello World</p></div>');
});

it("allows us to search with CSS selectors", function() {
    expect(elem).toBe('#containers');    // Problem happened here!!!!!!!
});});
```

Output Result:

```
Experimentation allows us to search with CSS selectors
Expected { 0 : HTMLNode, length : 1 } to be '#containers'.
Error: Expected { 0 : HTMLNode, length : 1 } to be '#containers'.
    at stack (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:1293:17)
    at buildExpectationResult (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:1270:14)
    at Spec.Env.expectationResultFactory (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:484:18)
    at Spec.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:260:46)
    at Expectation.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:442:21)
    at Expectation.toBe (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:1209:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/__spec__/experimentationSpec.js:9:16)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:1510:12)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:1498:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:1485:10)
```

Comment: Is it because the HTML string you're passing to `expect` is `#container` and not `#containers`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
elem = $('<div id="container"><p>Hello World</p></div>');

expect(elem).toBe('#containers');
```

You are comparing container with containers. Please note the extra 's'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still persisting with your problem even after changing it from #containers to #container, then try changing the function toBe() to toBeMatchedBy(). 
I too had the same problem with #container and by changing the function, it worked.